# Flutter web get files from ClipBoard

Tags: flutter, web

I want to copy files or content from the ClipBoard on Flutter web, I have tried all available packages and plugins but no things is working.
I need this because we have lot of files and images that users do with CTRl+V and we want to do it fast instead each time using filePicker, really fast and safe time if there a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

- [pasteboard](https://pub.dev/packages/pasteboard)
- [super_clipboard](https://pub.dev/packages/super_clipboard)

Packages.

Those packages are support to flutter web.